# How to generate wordpress login session

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i have try to make facebook login on woo-commerce my-account page below is my code..

js code

```
     jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: ajaxUrl,
            data: {
                action: "Generate_Session",
                username: response.name,
                email : response.email,
            },
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
     })
```

function.php is blelow

```
function Generate_Session()
 {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = '';
$email = $_POST['email'];
echo $username;
$gsdf='';
$user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
$user->set_role( 'seller' );

 add_filter('wp_authenticate_user', 'myplugin_auth_login',10,2);
  function myplugin_auth_login ($username, $password) {
 //do any extra validation stuff here
 return $user;
  }



wp_die();
 }
 // creating Ajax call for WordPress
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_Generate_Session', 'Generate_Session' );
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_Generate_Session', 'Generate_Session' );
```

WHen i get data into facebook login then i make new user as per my requirmnet..
then after i try to generate session varialbe. but i can't make it
when try to access woocommerce dashboard then it redirect on my-account page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your ajax function insert user with email and random password using wp_insert_user(). Then Use wp_signon() function below it.In wp_signon() function Use user name and password which you have used while creating user. Now you will be able to see user will be logged in. cheers